# Angular js $Interval weird behavior - Firefox Chrome

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome, firefox, intervals

I want to retrieve a Json Object every second in my Angular Controller.
My approach was to use $interval and it actually works. 
But in

Google Chrome - my interval count is about 200 per second 
Safari - same behaviour as in chrome 
Firefox - nothing happens at all, count=0

Code from the Controller:

```
(function(){

    var app = angular.module('timeDB',[])

    app.controller('listUserSupervisorController', ['$scope','$http','$interval', function($scope, $http, $interval){
        var count = 0;
        $interval(function(){
            $http.get('json/listUsers').then(function(res){
                $scope.userList = res.data;
                console.log("interval: "+count);
                count += 1;
            }), 1000
        });
    }]);

})();
```

Angular Version: 1.5.5 
Firefox Version: 45.0.2 
Google Chrome Version: 50.0.2661.94

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you put the 1000 in wrong place... it should be 1 level down, after curly bracket.